# Clarifying advice on strategizing use of Redux-saga, Redux-thunks, Context-Hooks, and/or React-query - with React project (Next possibly)

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit, react-query

I've been attempting to understand the relationship in using these in projects. Determining which is appropriate/advantages is making me go a little crazy and I don't want to assume that something is correct out of frustration - so I must submit and ask any of you if you would provide... some ELI5s with examples.
As I understand it, there are specific cases where some combinations might be redundant or unnecessary. I know the potentials concerns revolve around scaling, structure, capabilities, redundancy, learning-curve, to name a few (although I am least concerned with learning-curve and more so strategy, correct -usage, efficiency).

1. React + Redux-Thunk
2. React + Redux-Saga
3. React + Context-hooks (Can I use context-hooks simultaneously with Redux? Is there a point)
4. React + React-query (What purpose could this serve? To what extent? Advantageous/Disadvantages compared with other combonations?) - This is interesting because I believe Redux-toolkit comes with a similar thing to react-query
5. ? React + React-query + Context+ Redux-Saga/Thunk ? *Head exploded when I was imagining if this was possible and why*
   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As always, it depends! Your style, time, preference for magic over boilerplate, etc.

- I prefer using react [`Context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for local state shared between a specific group of containers/screens or dedicated local state, like theming.
- I've used [`thunks`](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks) and [`sagas`](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) and preferred `sagas`.
- If you are comfortable with thunks, then go for [`redux-toolkit`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) for reduced boilerplate.
- I am currently using [`react-query`](https://react-query.tanstack.com/) and loving it. But you won't miss it if you are comfortable with redux-toolkit.

---

Other opinions

- This StackOverflow question [What is the main difference between React Query and Redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68525459/what-is-the-main-difference-between-react-query-and-redux) has great answers.
- [Does React Query replace Redux, MobX or other global state managers?](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/does-this-replace-client-state)

  > The short answer is that React Query replaces the boilerplate code and related wiring used to manage cache data in your client-state and replaces it with just a few lines of code.

  > There are still some circumstances where an application might indeed have a massive amount of synchronous client-only state (like a visual designer or music production application), in which case, you will probably still want a client state manager. In this situation it's important to note that React Query is not a replacement for local/client state management. However, you can use React Query along side most client state managers with zero issues.
- Redux Thunks or Sagas? [What async middleware should I use? How do you decide between thunks, sagas, observables, or something else?](https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#what-async-middleware-should-i-use-how-do-you-decide-between-thunks-sagas-observables-or-something-else). Best to go with the Redux toolkit.

  > The Redux Toolkit package is intended to be the standard way to write Redux logic. It was originally created to help address three common concerns about Redux:
  >
  > - "Configuring a Redux store is too complicated"
  > - "I have to add a lot of packages to get Redux to do anything useful"
  >   "Redux requires too much boilerplate code".

---

As always, depends on your style, and most importantly the preference of your whole team.

Answer (score 0):

Reality is, all of these tools are pretty good and have their place. Which one you should use depends on both your use case and preference.

When building a new app you need to ask yourself some questions.

- How much global state do you plan to have?
- How often is the global state going to change?
- How much application logic/non-fetching side effects do you plan to have?
- How complex is this application going to be, do you want to have separation of view/data/applogic layers?
- How many people are going to work on this and for how long?
- How does the current ecosystem look like?
- Do you hate boilerplate or do you like bit of it of it to introduce structure and consistency into your project?
- How important is Typescript and proper typing to you?

#### If you plan to have only little or no global state or it is not going to change much:

I'd suggest to stick to React context & react-query for fetching. It will likely cover all your needs without any issues and there will be very little boilerplate.

#### If you plan to have lots of global state/its going to change often.

Use redux, when it comes to global state management it is the most mature solution with strong ecosystem and lots of tools and examples available. It is also still actively maintained and developed. See redux-toolkit for the modern way to work with redux. Redux-toolkit also includes redux-thunk and reselect by default. Thunks will cover your needs for the occasional extra side effect in addition to fetching.

**If most of your side effects are fetching data**

Use redux-query, you get the perfect combo of getting rid of most of boilerplate & fast early development while retaining the ability to manage well your global state and cache computed data.

**If you plan to have lots of application logic, managing different asynchronous processes that run for longer time etc.**

Use redux-saga, its very stable library that works great with redux for global state management. You can use it well even together with redux-query if you want to have the fetching part covered. One issue with sagas is that Typescript currently doesn't have great support for generator async runners. So you will need to explicitly type results of effects.

**Mixing async middleware**

It is possible to mix thunks & sagas together in one project, and it works well. Some people advocate to mix them based on your current use case others to stick to just one for consistency. Personally, If I end up adding sagas to a project I prefer to stick to them for everything just so I don't have to keep rewriting code between the two of them.

**Future**

The redux team is also working on a new experimental [action-listener-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rtk-incubator/action-listener-middleware) api, that will allow you to listen to actions similar to what sagas can do. I haven't tried it yet, but it is probably worth keeping your eyes on.

#### Do you plan to work on this project just yourself?

If so, pick whichever tool you find most fun. Keeping yourself motivated & learning new things is often the most important thing. You can have the best architecture there is, but if you are going to drop the project three days in, it won't help you. If on the other hand this is a company project with lots of people working on it and it will need to be maintained for a long time, try to pick the best tools for the job and to introduce some structure & consistency. Bit of boilerplate in large projects is usually a good thing as it helps in navigating the project and keeping it consistent. Having well maintained libraries with strong ecosystem behind them is a benefit too as it will make it easier to figure out how to bend them in the direction you will need.